# Constructor of Component is not working for the second time

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I have a Component class:

```
class AutoPage extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("Auto is " + this.props.route.params.auto);
    this.state = {
        avto: this.props.route.params.auto,
    }
    this.array = [
        this.state.avto.PICTURE,
    ];

    for (let dopImage of this.state.avto.DOP_FOTO.VALUE) {
        this.array.push(dopImage);
        //console.log(avto);
    }
    }
}
```

I am opening this Component from another place:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('AutoPage', {
                auto: item
              })}>
```

Here is my drawer navigation:

```
 <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <CustomSidebarMenu {...props} />} width={Dimensions.get('window').width - 130}
  component={CustomSidebarMenu}>
  <Stack.Screen name="AutoListPage" component={AvtoListPageNav} />
  <Stack.Screen name="AutoPage" component={AutoPage} options={{ headerTitle: "GorodAvtoPrime", headerTitleAlign: "center" }} /> 
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

When I click `TouchableOpacity` `AutoPage` opens and its constructor works. But when go back and click `TouchableOpacity` again, AutoPage opens and its constructor doesn't work. And I am getting previous data in `this.props.route.params.auto`. How can I make run constructor of `AutoPage` every time when I click `TouchableOpacity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to subscribe to the `focus` navigation event. The screen is being reused so it isn't created again.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events

```
class AutoPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        avto: null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // Update your state here
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you give a quick example of what should I fix in code above?

Comment: I added an example

Comment: I am new in react native, please help me. Wheere should I cann these methods?  How can I get avto property in componentDidMount method?